# How to read a randomly imported text file and store it in a list

Tags: python, list, import, tkinter

I use `file = askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])` to let the user choose what text file they'd like to import and I read it with `file.read()`. I've read on other questions with a similar idea but they only seem to cover what happens when you know the file name. I'd like to know how to read a text file and store the strings in a list in a situation where I don't know what file the user will choose to import. This is what I have so far:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

file = askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])
txt = file.read()
import_list = []
```

`import_list` is what I'd like the read file to be stored in.

Comment: What have you tried? There is literally no difference between `file=open('/some/file')` and `file=askopenfile(...)`.  Try something, and see what happens.

Comment: What I have up there prompts the user to select a file to upload with the dialog box then reads it. `file=open('/some/file)` means I have to know the name of the file or I have to change `/some/file` within another function or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the file content, you need to open it for reading (see the [Input/Output documentation, section 7.2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for the full options).

In your case, your code could look like this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

f = askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])

import_list = []

txt = f.read()

import_list.append(txt)
# import_list[-1] now contains txt

# ... any other operations on f.

f.close()
```

If what you want is import_list to be a list containing all the lines from the file, you can directly use the readlines() function:

```
import_list = f.readlines()
```

NB: I changed the variable name in which your store the file name from 'file' to 'file_name', as file is a built-in Type and naming your variable this way was shadowing it (see [Documentation, 5.9](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)).

Comment: In this code snippet, you're opening the file twice. Wouldn't that produce an error?

Comment: I meant to remove the first read, thanks for pointing it out. Remark that opening a file twice for reading does not produce an error.

Comment: If I run the above code and use a *.txt file, I get a `TypeError: Invalid file type`

Comment: `askiopenfile` returns an _already opened file_. It does _not_ return a filename. To return a filename you would call `askopenfilename` rather than `askopenfile`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to that. Bryan is right. The answer should have askopenfilename in the way it is, or askopenfile and then directly the part within the 'with' statement. I assume you would have to close the file too then.

Answer (score 2):

txt = file.read() stores the content of the as one String in txt.

If you want to split this string into a list of all lines, you should try the following:

```
import_list = txt.split('\n')
```